# HTML button redirect error

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

So I have been working with the [BootMetro](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/hub.html) framework and I came across a problem trying to create links on the icon buttons.

Part of the main header bar I created extra icons. However I cant seem to figure out how to turn the buttons into redirectable links:

```
        <div class="top-info-block">
           <b class="icon-blogger-2" onclick="window.location.href='www.blogger.com'"></b>
           <b class="icon-facebook-2"></b>
           <b class="icon-google-plus-3"></b>
           <b class="icon-youtube"></b>
        </div>
```

When using VS2012 I get a page not found error as the html link comes out as: `http://localhost:8581/www.blogger.com` is this just something with VS2012 or is my onclick method wrong?

Comment: No, not the wrong method.  you need to put the protocol (e.g. http://).  Any link without a protocol will assume relative link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `onclick="window.location.href='www.blogger.com'"` to `onclick="window.location.href='http://www.blogger.com'"`

Without the protocol (`http`), the `window.location.href` is trying to resolve `www.blogger.com` as a file/directory/ that is relative to your current location. In this case, `http://localhost:8581/`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. If your question has been answered please mark it as so.

Comment: Hey sorry SO has changed the time to accept answers to 15 minutes now. It did use to be 5min not sure why they want such a long wait.